# Makefile undefined reference to library

Tags: c, makefile

I know this is a very common question, but no matter where I looked I couldn't find a solution that worked.

I am writing an OS, and am also writing my own version of the c standard library, purely as a general interest type thing.  I have my c standard library, which currently consists only of an incomplete string.h, in the sb_libc folder in the kernel's main directory.  I can't use make to actually make the kernel if it includes my string.h header.  I keep getting "undefined reference to strcpy".  In order to test if I could include *anything*, I wrote two additional files, io.c and io_asm.s, and put their *.o files into the kernel's main directory.  I can link those with the kernel just fine.  Clearly, my library search paths are wrong in my make file.  I'll post it below.  If anyone can give me an idea on what I'm doing wrong, that would be great.

```
OBJECTS = loader.o io.o io_asm.o kmain.o ./sb_libc/string.o
CC = gcc
CFLAGS =  -e kmain -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -I./sb_libc/ -L./sb_libc/
LDFLAGS =  -T link.ld -melf_i386 -I./sb_libc/ -L./sb_libc/
AS = nasm
ASFLAGS = -f elf

all: kernel.elf

kernel.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    ld $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o kernel.elf

os.iso: kernel.elf
    cp kernel.elf iso/boot/kernel.elf
    genisoimage -R -b boot/grub/stage2_eltorito -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -A os -input-charset utf8 -quiet -boot-info-table -o os.iso iso

run: os.iso
    bochs -f bochsrc.txt -q

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $< -o $@

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o kernel.elf os.iso
```

Comment: Do `io.c` and `io_asm.s` use `strcpy`? If you haven't written `strcpy` yet, then what makes you think that anything is wrong with your paths?

Comment: Strcpy is what I was trying to link in. I wrote string.h and was trying to make it work. It resides in sb_libc folder.

Comment: You need to implement your own `strcpy` since you are not using standard standard c library

Comment: Yes, I know. strcpy is the function I wrote, and I'm now trying to link it in. It is in the folder ./sb_libc, which is a folder that resides in my kernel's directory. The function is implemented in string.c, which I wrote and tried to link in but it doesn't work

Comment: What `ld` command do you see Make execute? What happens if you invoke the `ld` on the command line? You must *simplify* this problem.